# How to get C from A and B in the following case?

Tags: python, list

How to get C from A and B in the following case?

```
A = ['5','6','7','8']
B = ['1','2','3','4']

C = [['5','1'],['6','2'],['7','3'],['8','4']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) or a list comprehension:

```
>>> map(list, zip(A, B))
[['5', '1'], ['6', '2'], ['7', '3'], ['8', '4']]
>>> [list(x) for x in  zip(A, B)]
[['5', '1'], ['6', '2'], ['7', '3'], ['8', '4']]
```

Comment: Would either one of these two choices be considered more pythonic?

Comment: @alecbenzer The advantage of LC is that it can be used as is in both Python2 and Python3, but for `map` you'll need an extra `list()` call in Python3.

Answer (score 2):

use zip: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

```
In [1]: A = [5,6,7,8]

In [2]: B = [1,2,3,4]

In [3]: zip(A,B)
Out[3]: [(5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 3), (8, 4)]

In [4]: map(list, zip(A, B))
Out[4]: [[5, 1], [6, 2], [7, 3], [8, 4]]

In [5]: [list(x) for x in  zip(A, B)]
Out[5]: [[5, 1], [6, 2], [7, 3], [8, 4]]
```

EDIT: added In [4] through Out[5]

Comment: That's a list of tuples rather than a list of lists

Comment: Sure, but he can apply a list comprehension or `map` as others have suggested

Comment: ok, fine i'll add it, i don't like stepping on others' answers but that seems to be the norm around here

Comment: Since your answer seems to be at the top, you may as well add the `list()`. I think it's better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
>>> [list(t) for t in zip(A, B)]
[['5', '1'], ['6', '2'], ['7', '3'], ['8', '4']]
```

If you do plain: `zip(A, B)` then you get a list of tuples which is not strictly what you asked for:

```
>>> zip(A, B)
[('5', '1'), ('6', '2'), ('7', '3'), ('8', '4')]
```

So apply `list()` to each tuple that comes out of `zip` to get what you asked for.